# What’s the Accepted Procedure for questions that have been answered on another Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, migration

“[Vim74: E149 Sorry no help for help.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145819/vim74-e149-sorry-no-help-for-help-txt#comment28416846_19145819)” on Stack Overflow seems (to me) to be asking much the same question as “[Vim - errors E433 No tags file, E149 No help for help.txt](https://superuser.com/questions/515699/vim-errors-e433-no-tags-file-e149-no-help-for-help-txt)” on Super User. That second question [has what I think is a good answer](https://superuser.com/a/584945/230861), but of course that’s not on Stack Overflow, and I’m not sure that such a question doesn’t *belong* on Stack Overflow (nor even that it instead doesn’t belong on Super User).

I don’t necessarily like the idea of an answer simply saying “See the answer to this question on Super User” (and indeed, although I did attempt to post such an answer, it was deemed Trivial and converted to a comment), but in the case of a user coming across this question (say) by means of searching, I’d like there to at least be a link to the answer on Super User so that the question isn’t a dead end. What’s generally supposed to be done in this sort of case?

Comment: +1, [happened to me once before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041620/regarding-ftp-rawlist-what-is-file-or-directory-number#comment28139820_19041620). I wouldn't mind being able to mark as duplicate cross-site.

Comment: Note that [you should never have an answer just containing a link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/206447) (nor should you copy an answer from elsewhere on the Stack Exchange network). A comment is more appropriate.

Comment: In the question which this was marked as a duplicate of, I didn’t see advice on how *to* answer a question such as this — only that it could be migrated, which, as I thought I made clear in the question, I don’t think is the solution — this could well be an on-topic and helpful Q/A on both sites. Stack Overflow is left therefore with a question which remains “unanswered” and no non-comment means of directing someone who finds it to where there’s an actual answer.